# The most efficient way to implement a database using custom data + google fitness api

Tags: android, database, google-fit, custom-data-type

I am currently learning android programming and creating an app that will store some integers representing user choices (values inserted several times a day, must be displayed in the results activity) and steps data collected Google Fit HISTORY Android APIs, also displayed in the results activity. I am looking for the most efficient way to store this data. I know that it might be possible to insert the custom data types in the GOOGLE fit database. However, I am not sure if it is a good idea if the app mostly works offline, and it needs to immediately represent only a small set of results, for example, the values inserted in the last 2 weeks, with step counts. On the other hand, I am not sure if it is ok to have two databases storing the data.

My apologies if the question sounds a bit too amateur, I am doing my best to find an optimal solution in terms of performance.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to give you my opinion and answer (mainly opinion)

Android has 3 ways (mainly) for storing data:

1. Files
2. Online database/API
3. Local database

for this specific scenario you have listed, wanting the data to be available offline, you should probably be looking at using Room: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room, as it supports storing primitive types without having to write any type converters, you can store models and custom data as well, it uses very basic SQL (because it's a wrapper for the older Sqlite database methods) and is part of android (not an external 3rd party library). Room also requires most operations to be done off of threads, instead of main threads and this will improve your performance as well (also has support for livedata/rxjava to observe straight onto any changes as they happen)

However, as I told this user here:
[Should i store one arrayList per file or should i store all my arrayList in the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098645/should-i-store-one-arraylist-per-file-or-should-i-store-all-my-arraylist-in-the/57098921#57098921) 
When starting out, don't worry about the best way for doing something, instead, try something out and learn from it, worrying about the best solution now is rather pointless, either way, happy learning and coding :P